# Modifying a node of an x3d scene produce no result

Tags: javascript, x3d

I'm using x3d scene in a web page. In this page, I have an `indexedfaceset` which works fine.
I'm adding a `<Color color="..."></Color>` and it's working fine as well.

Now what I'm trying to do is to change the content of the `Color` using javascript once the scene is already drawn. Unfortunately the modifications aren't taken into account.

Do I have to force a redraw of the scene or something like that? I saw nothing on the runtime api of x3d.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

through x3dom?

if so check out my answer here. shows how to set attributes through both tag and id on js mouse events

i know your trying to change index face set color attribute but i think the below should give u a starting point. let me know if you need a more concise example

[attaching attribute to x3dom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603444/attaching-attribute-to-x3dom-object)

Comment: Thanks. Yes it's trough x3dom. I don't have problem to get and set elements. The only probleme is that for an indexedfaceset, modifying the color tag after the object was drawn has no effect. A workaround that I'm using is to remove the whole indexedfaceset and reinsert it. It's working just fine like that.